# C++ Call subclass method from superclass

Tags: c++, class, superclass

I have code of the following style:

```
class SubClass;
class SuperClass;

class SuperClass {

private:

    void bar() {

        SubClass().foo();
    }
};

class SubClass : SuperClass {

public:

    void foo() {};
};
```

So basically I have a SuperClass from where I want to call a method foo() of the subclass.
VS 2012 gives me the following errors:

Error 1 error C2514: 'SubClass' : class has no constructors.

Error 2 error C2228: left of '.foo' must have class/struct/union.

What is the correct structure for what I want to do?

Comment: `virtual void foo();`?

Comment: You should not want to do this.

Comment: This is a very good and useful thing to want to do. Its why virtual functions were added to c++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do this. You must (at least) declare the method in the base class. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class SuperClass 
{
public:
    void bar() 
    {
        foo();
    }
private:
    virtual void foo() // could be pure virtual, if you like
    {
        std::cout << "SuperClass::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass // do not forget to inherit public
{
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "SubClass::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    SuperClass* pTest = new SubClass;

    pTest -> bar();

    delete pTest;
}
```

will print `SubClass::foo()`.

Comment: what does the "public" keyword mean in "class SubClass : public SuperClass" ?

Comment: @ErbenMo - `public` inheritance (it can also be `private` and `protected`)

Comment: thank you. This allows to call the foo() method of any subclass of "SuperClass". What I needed this for: `vector<Employees*> employees` stores objects of `Secretary`, `FootBoy`, `CEO` and so on. Each of them is a sub class of `Employee` and they all have an operate() method, implemented very differently of course. With this solution, it's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with some CRTP,
ie:

```
#include <iostream>

class SubClass;

template<typename T>
class SuperClass {
private:
    void bar() {
        ((T *) this)->foo();
    }
public:
    void foobar() {
        this->bar();
    }
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass<SubClass> {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "hello crtp!" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main(void){
    SubClass a = SubClass();
    a.foobar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to realise that calling `SubClass().foo()` has nothing to do with the current object - it will create a new `SubClass` object and call its `foo` member. If you want the `bar` function to call `foo` on the current object, you need to declare `foo` as a virtual function in the base class, as Kiril suggested.

However, if you do want to call `foo` on a new object (which doesn't make much sense, but whatever), you are doing it correctly. Your example didn't compile because `SubClass` is forward declared, but not defined before `bar` function - you might want to move the implementation of `bar` below the definition of `SubClass`, like so:
    class SubClass;
    class SuperClass;

```
class SuperClass {

private:

    void bar();
};

class SubClass : SuperClass {

public:

    void foo() {};
};

void SuperClass::bar() {
    SubClass().foo();
}
```